# Why does my dog now have spots showing underneath his fur on his chest?

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition

[image: Picture of spots]

My dog is three years old and has recently started developing what looks like big, dark freckles on his chest. I can see them because the hair on his chest is white and his hair is not particularly very long. Is this normal?

Comment: Hi, could you please take a photo of this and include it in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spots in your picture look like **hyperpigmentation**, comparable to freckles in humans.

They are actually very common and usually appear with age. They can affect the skin, nails and even the tongue and other mucous membranes. Most people just don't notice them under the fur of their dog.

As long as these spots are not accompanied by any other symptoms, they are completely harmless.

If you notice any change in behavior, especially **scratching or licking of the affected area** or if the skin **has a different texture** (is thicker or rougher than normal), you need to have a vet analyze the cause of the spots. They could be caused by:

- allergies (food allergy)
- parasites
- bacterial or fungal infections
- other stressors like constant friction on the skin.

You can read more about it [here](https://herepup.com/black-spot-on-dog-skin/).